# CodeIgniter - Mod_Rewrite on One.com hosting service

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm really starting to regret buying a domain at One.com

I have a simple CI project set up that works perfectly on localhost, but one.com isn't my friend. I can't seem to get mod_rewrite working. I don't even bother contacting support, because I'm getting the feeling that anyone who needs more than an index page isn't welcome there.

This is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /luc/

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#‘system’ can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn’t true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
#Submitted by Michael Radlmaier (mradlmaier)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|js|UberGallery|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don’t have mod_rewrite installed, all 404’s
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

And in CI config:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';//I have tried the full URI.
$config['index_page'] = ''; 
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; //I have tried REQUEST_URI as well.
```

luc is a subdomein of my domain, hence the RewriteBase in .htaccess.
In all my subfolders, I have an .htaccess file with deny from all.
This seems to be a one.com specific issue, so I hope there's someone experienced enough to spot an error in my setup.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get when you access your website? A 500 error, a 404, nothing...

Comment: Other thing, how do you access your website? with luc.mywebsite.com?

Comment: is that your complete `.htaccess` file or are there parts you are not showing us?

Comment: I get a 404 page. A 500 page would be a loop right? I fixed that earlier to no avail.

Comment: The complete domain name is v-art.be/luc.
I've posted my entire .htaccess file by the way